# Subquery or INNER JOIN?

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables that represent something like attachments to emails.  Accordingly, emails have zero, one or more attachments.

The three tables are `Emails`, `Attachments` and `Files`.

`Emails` - Each row refers to one email and contains a MessageID

`Attachments` - Each row contains a MessageID and a FileID.  There can be multiple rows with the same Message ID.

`Files` - Each row refers to one File and contains a FileID and the file size (Size)

I am trying to get a result in mysql that contains a list of EmailID and the total size of all files and having no success.  I can get the total of the size of the files using a `SUM(Size)` and an `INNER JOIN`, but I can't get a list of EmailID's and total file Sizes.

Should this use multiple `INNER JOIN`s? `INNER JOIN` and a subquery? And then a `GROUP BY`?  Subquery and then an `IN`.  Even a direction here would be really helpful.

Iterating in PHP seems ridiculously expensive.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    e.msgID,
    SUM(f.size)
FROM emails e
INNER JOIN attachments a
    ON a.msgID = e.msgID
INNER JOIN files f
    ON f.fID = a.fID
GROUP BY e.msgID
```

I think that should do the trick.

Comment: Now that's pretty.  And fast.  Thanks!! (I can't say I get the order of how the GROUP BY getting applied clicks for me yet, but it works and I'll stare at it for a long while.)